# Else statement not recognised java

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

```
 private void EnterbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    if (Usernamefield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("User"));
    if (Passwordfield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("420"));
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome, User!");   
}                                           
else 
{

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username/Password!");

}
```

It says that an else statement cannot work without an if, there are clearly 2 if statements however. I would like to create a simple log-in GUI in Java.

Comment: I hope this is just a test or school assignment, and not for production code. Otherwise never implement your own security.

Comment: You have Semicolons after the `if` statements; that causes the problem you're seeing. Basically you're telling the computer `if <x> then do <empty statement>`. Twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
    if (Usernamefield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("User"));
    if (Passwordfield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("420"));
```

to

```
if (Usernamefield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("User") && 
    Passwordfield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("420"))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome, User!");   
}                                           
else 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username/Password!");
}
```

You want both conditions to be true in order to accept the user. 

And don't put a `;` at the end of an if condition, since that makes it an empty if statement that does nothing (that's the reason your `else` had no matching `if`).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
 private void EnterbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

     if (Usernamefield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("User")  && Passwordfield.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("420"))
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome, User!");   
     }                                           
     else 
     {    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username/Password!");    
     }
```